# HTML5 Select in Angularjs is missing second keydown event

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select

```
<script>
    var appMod = angular.module('myapp', []);
    appMod.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


      $scope.DefaultOptions = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"];


    }]);
</script>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div>
    <select ng-options="o as o for o in DefaultOptions" ng-model="chosen"></select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Chosen Value: <span ng-bind="chosen"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Instructions:
  1. In Chrome(not in Firefox!), select the dropdown with mouse and choose "First"
  2. Then press downarrow.
  3. Observe that the dropdown shows "Second" while the dynamically binded value still shows "Frist"
  4. Press downarrow again.
  5. Now both the select as well as binded field are showing "Third".
  6. Clearly, there is some "magic" happening in angular with respect to second keydown event or is the ng-options used incorrectly here?
  7. This happens always, even if you choose "Third" instead of "First" in first step.

Here is the plunker for the question in title.

http://embed.plnkr.co/x7dauZHIlriXpWd4kmgz/preview

Can someone please explain is this a bug in Angularjs or some problem in my usage of ng-options?

PS: I thought, of all the browsers, Chrome would be the nicest to Angularjs.

Comment: In background Angular Binding works on value and by default there is no  selected value. That might be the case.

Comment: You can use ng-repeat for that

Comment: @HaRdikKaji The dropdown and binding both get updated properly on first keydown event. So there is no question of default selected value here. Its all about second keydown event.

Comment: While investigating, I saw other stackoverflow questions and their plunker code had the same problem of navigating select element through keyboard. For Ex/- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574081/angularjs-how-to-use-select-with-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-options="o as o for o in DefaultOptions" ng-model="chosen">
  <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Choose an option</option>         
</select>
```

Found the answer(rather a weird trick to weird behaviour). If an option is  specified in the above manner, then dropdown can safely be navigated through keyboard. Who could have thought of that!